# a == b, exponential notation. Octave weirdness?

Tags: octave

If I type this into octave:

```
a = 8*10^-5;
b = 8.0e-005;
a==b
```

I get the answer:

```
ans = 1
```

But if I type this into octave:

```
a = 3*10^-5;
b = 3.0e-005;
a==b
```

I get this answer

```
ans = 0
```

Am I missing something?  Is this not the right way to test for equality?

Comment: What does `a-b` give in each case?

Comment: In the first case (where a==b returns 1), a-b returns 0.  In the second case (where a==b returns 0), a-b returns 3.3881e-021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with the way floating point numbers are represented in computer systems.

Many numbers which are 'round' in decimal become repeating fractions in the binary representation used by the computer, and they have to be truncated at some point, for a very slight loss of precision. If two floating point numbers are arrived at differently, you have to compare them with a little bit of slop, e.g. `abs(a-b) < EPSILON` where `EPSILON` is an appropriate constant like 1e-12.

Answer (score 3):

This is a result of loss of precision during computations involving floating point numbers, for example in Java `3 * Math.pow(10, -5)` would give you '2.9999999999999997E-5' which no longer matches b in your second example. This is linked to how floating point values are represented and evolve during the evaluation of an expression. For more elaborate perspectives, you can google 'loss of precision' suffixing that with the context / environment you are using to evaluate these expressions. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I now think I understand what happened.  I was using the identical notation to test for equality, a==3*10^-5, that I used to create the variable, "a=3*10^-5".  But I ran the test after saving and reloading the data, so perhaps the precision got changed during the save.  (Still don't understand why the problem happens only when the multiplier is 3.  Works ok when the multiplier is a different digit.)  In any case, I've got my code working now.

Comment: Good to hear you are up and running. There should be other values apart from 3 that play up as well, e.g. 5. Indeed, saving and retrieving the result can introduce some unexpected behaviors, especially if the transit variable types are different - e.g. float versus double.